# calling resolve from callback function in angular

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

In my angular application i have to return the resolve form a the function callback.

Sample code:

```
new testPromise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   abc("test",successCallback,errorCallback)    
});
```

How can i call the resolve/reject from the callback functions

such as:

```
successCallback(data){
  resolve(data);

}
errorCallback(error){
  reject(error);
}
```

Is this possible or will i have to call the resolve/reject from inside the promise only?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass them directly *as* the callback arguments:

```
let testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    abc("test", resolve, reject);
});
```

Do not create separate functions such as `function successCallback(data) { resolve(data); }` inside the promise constructor.